# Debug CloudFormation validation issue

Tags: validation, debugging, aws-cloudformation

I am using a linter and my template appears valid, yet my deployment is failing with a "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule Validation exception".  There does not appear to be any place to further drill down on this exception in the Cloud Formation console.  How do I determine why my deployment is invalid?

---

## Cloud Formation template

```yaml
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String

Mappings:
  EnvMap:
    sandbox:
      ...

Resources:
  HttpsListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !FindInMap [EnvMap, !Ref Env, CertificateArn]
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            # TODO: read all this stuff off HTTP listener
            TargetGroupStickinessConfig:
              Enabled: false
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn:
                  !FindInMap [EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerDefaultTargetArn]
                Weight: 1
          TargetGroupArn:
            !FindInMap [EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerDefaultTargetArn]
      LoadBalancerArn: !FindInMap [EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerArn]
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS

  HttpsListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroupStickinessConfig:
              Enabled: false
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn:
                  !FindInMap [EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerRouteTargetArn]
                Weight: 1
          TargetGroupArn:
            !FindInMap [EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerRouteTargetArn]
      Conditions:
        - Field: path-pattern
          PathPatternConfig:
            Values:
              - /*
          Values:
            - /*
      ListenerArn: !Ref HttpsListener
      Priority: 50000
```

## Error

"Status Reason" from the event.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule Validation exception" (RequestToken: 16bd4239-0d41-b16f-2963-b0a774009dfd, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Comment: What is the actual template and the full error message?

Comment: Just updated...  Is it maybe because i reference ARNs of resources managed outside my stack?

Comment: try run cfn-lint against your template

Comment: was your issue resolved? try the solution below ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `PathConfigPattern` from the `Conditions` key:

```yaml
HttpsListenerRule:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
  Properties:
    Actions:
      - Type: "forward"
        ForwardConfig:
          TargetGroupStickinessConfig:
            Enabled: false
          TargetGroups:
            - TargetGroupArn: !FindInMap [ EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerRouteTargetArn ]
              Weight: 1
        TargetGroupArn: !FindInMap [ EnvMap, !Ref Env, LoadBalancerRouteTargetArn ]
        Order: 1
    Conditions:
      - Field: path-pattern
        Values:
          - "/*"
    ListenerArn: !Ref HttpsListener
    Priority: 50000
```

Also, make sure your `EnvMap` map looks like this:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    Default: sandbox

Mappings:
  EnvMap:
    sandbox:
      LoadBalancerRouteTargetArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:111111111111:targetgroup/my-tg-1/222222222222"
    prod:
      LoadBalancerRouteTargetArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:333333333333:targetgroup/my-tg-2/444444444444"
```